# On a complex group rings of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, group-rings

Let $G$, $K$ and $H$ be three finite groups where $H$ acts on both of $G$ and $K$ as sets nontrivially. Moreover assume that $\mathbb{C}K$ is (isomorphic to) a $\mathbb{C}H$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$ (where $\mathbb{C}$ is field of complex numbers).

Is it true that $K$ must be (isomorphic to) a $H$-subgroup of $G$?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. $H$ could act on $G$ trivially, and then $\mathbb C K$ would always be a $\mathbb C H$-submodule of $G$. Do you maybe mean to claim that $K$ is an $H$-subset of $G$ ?

Comment: I made some editions to turn question into what I exactly mean.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  I want to know whether or not K is (isomorphic to) a H-subgroup of G.

Answer (score 1):

The group structures of $G$ and $K$ don't affect the hypotheses, so you shouldn't expect to be able to deduce much about them.

For **any** groups with $|K|<|G|$ and any action of $H$ on $K$, you could just identify $K$ (as a set) with some subset $K'$ of $G$, and let $H$ act on $G$ by acting the same way on $K'$ as it does on $K$, and in an arbitrary way on $G\setminus K'$. Then $\mathbb{C}G\cong\mathbb{C}K\oplus\mathbb{C}[G\setminus K']$ as $\mathbb{C}H$-modules, so $\mathbb{C}K$ is ismomorphic to a $\mathbb{C}H$-submodule of $\mathbb{C}G$.

Comment: Thank you, That's right. But generally how can we recognize $H$-subgroups of $G$ for an arbitrary action of $H$ on $G$? Is there any source about $H$-invariant subgroups of $G$ (for an arbitrary action, not just actions by automorphisms)?